# 2 player game subtracting perfect squares from a given number

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

this is my first question on these forums.  I apologize in advance if I've overlooked a rule or done something wrong.  Unfortunately, I can't remember where I came across this problem, but it's been bothering me for some time.  I'd appreciate any sort of help here.

The Question:
Two people, $A$ and $B$, are playing a game.  Given some number $N$, $A$ subtracts a perfect square less than or equal to $N$ from $N$.  $B$ then subtracts a perfect square less than the resulting number from that number.  And so on.  The winner is the last person to subtract a number.
Determine all $N$ such that $A$ has a winning strategy.

An Example:
$N=13$; $A$ subtracts $1$, $B$ subtracts $9/4/1$, $A$ subtracts $1/1/9$, $B$ subtracts $1/(1 or 4)/1$, $A$ subtracts $1/(4 or 1)/1$, $B$ subtracts $-*/1/-*$, $A$ subtracts $-/1/-$, $B$ subtracts$-/-*/-$.  Since $A$ can force $B$ to lose regardless of how $B$ plays, $A$ wins.

Work I've done so far:
We say a number $x$ is a winning number if $A$ has a strategy for winning when $N=x$ and is a losing number if $A$ doesn't have a strategy for winning when $N=x$.  Note that if $x$ is a winning number, then there exists a perfect square $k^2$ such that $x-k^2$ is losing.  Also, if $x$ is a losing number then for any $k^2$, $x-k^2$ is a winning number.  The difference between any $2$ losing numbers can never be a perfect square.  We also note that, if $x-L$ (where $L$ is any losing number less than $x$) isn't a perfect square, then $x$ can't be a winning number.  So, using this I found a recursive means of computing some losing numbers $(0,2,5,7,10,12...)$.  The losing numbers didn't seem to have a pattern, so I figured I'd try showing that there were only a finite number and then bashing through the recursion to find them all.  But as it turns out there are infinitely many losing numbers.  I'm at a dead end here, which probably means I'm overlooking a trick of some sort.

Research:
I did a google search of something along the lines of "game subtracting perfect squares" and didn't find anything helpful.  I also checked a few of the related posts that Stack Exchange had as "Questions that may have your answer" and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34687/two-elementary-games-in-number-theory) looked similar, but it wasn't particularly useful since parity doesn't seem to be very helpful in this problem.  I posted this question on another math forum as well, but I haven't gotten a response.

Comment: Presumably you mean a **nonzero** perfect square.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: How about if you find complete solutions for $N=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ because the only nonzero squares involved  are $1,4.$ Tell us how it works out.

Comment: The question is resolved, but for completeness sake: 1,3=1+1+1,4,6=1+(1/4)+(4/1),8=1+(1/4)+(4/1) are winning numbers and 2=1+1,5=(1/4)+(4/1), and 7=(1/4)+(4/1)+1+1 are losing numbers

Answer (score 3):

The losing numbers are OEIS sequence [A030193](http://oeis.org/A030193)

Comment: Thanks, I thought the answer would be less involved.  If you don't mind me asking, how did you know that so quickly?

Comment: I entered 0,2,5,7,10,12 in the search box at oeis.org.

Comment: I see, thanks again for the help :)